# Український відповідник до слова "аватар"

Tags: вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова

Потрібно знайти відповідник до слова "[аватар](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80_(%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82))", яке сьогодні часто можна зустріти, коли йдеться про соціальні мережі. Його значення: "Невелике статичне або анімоване зображення".

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/avatar) першим та найкращим варіантом пропонує "мармизка", та якщо ми заглянемо в СУМ, то побачимо, що його там немає, однак є слово "[мармиза](http://sum.in.ua/s/marmyza)", але воно є вульгаризмом, та й значення у нього: "Обличчя", однак "аватаром" не обов'язково має бути обличчя людина, а може бути зображення чого-небудь. Та й "українська мармизка" звучить дещо дивно.

Comment: Аватар — це не будь-яке «невелике статичне або анімоване зображення», а саме таке, що **представляє людину** (взагалі чи в конкретному повідомленні, адже в деяких системах до різних повідомлень можна чіпляти різні аватари). Відповідно аватар справді є **(віртуальним) обличчям** людини, навіть якщо на ньому зображено слона в повний зріст або портфель. Тому один з Ваших аргументів проти мармизки здається мені некоректним (хоча того, що слово є вульгаризмом, і того, що в деяких контекстах «мармизка» звучить недоречно, заперечити не можу).

Comment: На мою думку, не може існувати достатньо точного і питомого українського відповідника запозиченню індуїстького терміну з санскриту в англійський жаргон комп’ютерних ігор, бо 1) є певні неточності при перекладі українською оригінального терміну 2) жаргон комп’ютерних ігор також, з очевидних причин, є запозиченням

Comment: "Аватар" вживається не лише в жаргоні комп’ютерних ігор, якщо бути точним, та й я взагалі про них не згадував у питанні, там це слово можна легко замінити, наприклад словосполученням "портрет персонажа".

Comment: Згідно англійської Вікіпедії, слово Аватар запозичили в англійську для позначення «репрезентації» гравця у комп’ютерній грі десь у 80-х роках двадцятого сторіччя. А вже пізніше, коли з‘явився інтернет і інтернет-форуми, мессенджери та інше, слово запозичили з субкультури комп’ютерних ігор

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Всемережеві англіцизми](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mJcpvbLuVsjiEpvySqnKbKv0flhOoDvL/view?usp=sharing)

Аватар - личина, світлина, мармизка.

З СУМ-11

> [Личина](http://sum.in.ua/s/lychyna) 2.перен. Удавана зовнішність людини.

Можливо, що це кращий варіант за інші два, хоча в [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47675&page=1503) цього значення в статті "личина" вже немає.

СУМ-11

> [Світлина](http://sum.in.ua/s/svitlyna) . зах., заст. Фотографія.
>
> [Мармиза](http://sum.in.ua/s/marmyza) и, жін., вульг. Обличчя.

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://theoptymist.wordpress.com/2015/10/29/%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%96-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB/) ще пропонують варіант:

> **образок**.

Однак на інших сайтах ([1](http://ms.detector.media/web/online_media/yak_udoskonaliti_svoyu_ukrainsku_pyat_onlaynresursiv/), [2](https://dzerkalo.media/malo-pridumati-treba-shhe-y-govoriti/) та ін.) всюди пропонують варіант "мармизка".